# How to render properly a Full calendar in agendaDay view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How to render properly a Full calendar for agendaDay view. Its not rendering the agendaDay view.

It's only rendering while the clicking on 'next', 'previous' or on the 'today' buttons. I want to show today's agenda by using agendaDay.

Is there any way to make the today as default render on this below given javascript ?

Please suggest.

[image]

```
var Calendar = function () {
  var a = function () {
    var a = $("#event-management");

    $("#event-categories div.event-category").each(function () {
      var a = {
        title: $.trim($(this).text())
      };
      $(this).data("eventObject", a), $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: !0,
        revertDuration: 50
      })
    });
    var b = new Date,
      c = b.getDate(),
      d = b.getMonth(),
      e = b.getFullYear(),
      f = "",
      g = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({

        themeButtonIcons: {
          prev: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
          next: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        header: {
          //left: "prev,next today",
          left: "prev,next today",
          right: "title",
          // right: "agendaDay,agendaWeek,month"
        },

        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        drop: function (a, b) {
          var c = $(this).data("eventObject"),
            d = $(this).attr("data-class"),
            e = $.extend({}, c);
          e.start = a, e.allDay = b, d && (e.className = [d]), $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", e, !0), $("#drop-remove").is(":checked") && $(this).remove()
        },



        select: function (b, c, d) {
          a.modal({
            backdrop: "static"
          }), f = $("<form></form>"), f.append("<div class='row'></div>"), f.find(".row").append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Schedule an activity</label><input class='form-control' placeholder='Activity Name' type=text name='title'/></div></div>").append("<div class='col-md-6'><div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Category</label><select class='form-control' name='category'></select></div></div>").find("select[name='category']").append("<option value='label-default'>Work</option>").append("<option value='label-green'>Home</option>").append("<option value='label-purple'>Holidays</option>").append("<option value='label-orange'>Party</option>").append("<option value='label-yellow'>Birthday</option>").append("<option value='label-teal'>Generic</option>").append("<option value='label-beige'>To Do</option>"), a.find(".remove-event").hide().end().find(".save-event").show().end().find(".modal-body").empty().prepend(f).end().find(".save-event").unbind("click").click(function () {
            f.submit()
          }), a.find("form").on("submit", function () {
            return title = f.find("input[name='title']").val(), $categoryClass = f.find("select[name='category'] option:checked").val(), null !== title && g.fullCalendar("renderEvent", {
              title: title,
              start: b,
              end: c,
              allDay: d,
              className: $categoryClass
            }, !0), a.modal("hide"), !1
          }), g.fullCalendar("unselect")
        },
        eventClick: function (b, c, d) {
          var e = $("<form></form>");
          e.append("<label>Change event name</label>"), e.append("<div class='input-group'><input class='form-control' type=text value='" + b.title + "' /><span class='input-group-btn'><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Save</button></span></div>"), a.modal({
            backdrop: "static"
          }), a.find(".remove-event").show().end().find(".save-event").hide().end().find(".modal-body").empty().prepend(e).end().find(".remove-event").unbind("click").click(function () {
            g.fullCalendar("removeEvents", function (a) {
              return a._id == b._id
            }), a.modal("hide")
          }), a.find("form").on("submit", function () {
            return b.title = e.find("input[type=text]").val(), g.fullCalendar("updateEvent", b), a.modal("hide"), !1
          })
        }
      })
  };
  return {
    init: function () {
      a()

    }
  }
}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to give today's date to default date.

You can try this in your calendar script.

```
defaultDate = new Date();
```

This is the link you can read.
 https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultDate

Comment: $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date()
})